# Update Current Page or Update Data in Paging 3 library Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, nestedrecyclerview, android-paging-library, android-paging-3

I am new in Paging 3 library in android kotlin. I want unlimited data. So I found Paging 3 library is helpful in my case. I used **PagingSource** to create a list. I am not using Room. I have **nested** recyclerView. I am using **PagingDataAdapter** with **diff util** for my Recyclerview. I used the recommended tutorial for Paging library from **codelab** and I succeeded without any problem. I am facing difficult to update the item. I used paging source to create list and inside list i have some data which are coming from sever. I completely all this without any problem. But how to update adapter or notify data has changed in reyclerview. I already mechanism to fetch updated list. I searched how to update the adapter in some place but every where is mention to use **invalidate()** from **DataSource**. **DataSource** is used in **paging 2** right?. Now this is inside the Paging 3 as per Documentation in [Migrate to Paging 3](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-migration). I used Flow to retrieve data. This code is inside **viewmodel** class.

```
fun createRepo(data: List<String>, repository: RepositoryData): Flow<PagingData<UnlimitData>> {
    return repository.getStreamData(data).cachedIn(viewModelScope)
}
```

I am passing list, which is coming from sever. **getStreamData** function return the items with int and string data. My Data class

```
data class UnlimitData(val id: Int, val name: String)
```

**createRepo** is calling in my activity class to send data in adpater.

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
        viewModel.createRepo(serverData,repository).collectLatest { data ->
            adapter.submitData(data)
        }
}
```

This is my Adapter code:-

```
class unlimitedAdapter() :
    PagingDataAdapter<UnlimitData, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(COMPARATOR) {

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = getItem(position)
    if (item != null) {
        (holder as UnlimitedViewHolder).bind(item)
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    return UnlimitedViewHolder.create(parent)
}

companion object {
    private val COMPARATOR = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<UnlimitData>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: UnlimitData, newItem: UnlimitData): Boolean =
            oldItem.id == newItem.id

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: UnlimitData, newItem: UnlimitData): Boolean = oldItem == newItem
    }
}
```

}

I added logic to insert/Update data in list using RetroFit. My list is updated successfully, but i am unable to refresh reyclerview.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

In order for paging to pick up new items, you will need to call `PagingSource.invalidate()` to inform `Pager` that it needs to fetch a new `PagingSource` and reload pages. You'll want to keep track of all the `PagingSource`s your factory produces and invalidate them anytime you update the backing dataset from network.

EDIT: Something like this, but this is a very rough prototype

```
abstract class InvalidatingPagingSourceFactory<K,V> : () -> PagingSource<K,V> {
    private val list = mutableListOf()

    abstract fun create()

    override final fun invoke() {
        create().also { list.add(it) }
    }

    fun invalidate() {
        while (list.isNotEmpty()) { list.removeFirst().invalidate() }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @dlam thanks for response. Can you please explain me in detail how to track of all PagingSource. I am new in Paging library. Thanks

Comment: In the `PagingSourceFactory` you pass to `Pager`, you'll need something that keeps a list of refs to the `PagingSource`s you create, and have some kind of callback that tells you when your backing dataset changes and invalidates + clears that list. Some sample code in this bug might help you get started: https://issuetracker.google.com/160716447

Comment: Hi @dlam thanks for reply. Can i get more clear working example.

Comment: Did you click the link?

Comment: Is there anything specific I could help expand on? You essentially need to call `.invalidate()` (which is also a pagingsource API) to get Paging to create a new `PagingSource` using the Factory you provided to reload data.

What have you tried and what doesn't work?

Comment: @dlam I saw your commit about InvalidatingPagingSourceFactory. How can I access this InvalidatingPagingSourceFactory and surface it from a PagingDataAdapter or ViewModel ?

Comment: `InvalidatingPagingSourceFactory` is just a helper class which tracks all the `PagingSource` it creates, so you can invalidate with a single function call instead of tracking them yourself. You would pass it into `Pager()` which requires a `() -> PagingSource` for the `pagingSourceFactory`.

Comment: @dlam At the moment my ViewModel only has access to the `Pager`'s `flow()`, which returns a `Flow<PagingData<Value>>`, so at that point the access to the `Pager` is already lost. Does that mean that I have to save the `Pager` somewhere in the ViewModel in order to use it? It wouldn't be very convenient as in order to achieve that, the ViewModel, which was agnostic of the data source before, will now need to save one Pager for every data source (local and remote). Do you have a concrete sample project to illustrate the use of `InvalidatingPagingSourceFactory` ?

Comment: You don't need to pass the `Pager` around, you just need to pass `InvalidatingPagingSourceFactory` in `Pager` and keep a reference of `InvalidatingPagingSourceFactory` around.

What you want to do, is to hook up `InvalidatingPagingSourceFactory.invalidate()` to your source of truth. So it depends on how you intend to listen to that. What layer is your `Pager` defined in, and where do you expect external invalidation signals to come from?

Comment: Wherever you declare your `Pager`, you should have access to the repository layer because you need to give `Pager` the repository abstraction, `PagingSource`, which should also give you access to your external signal used to trigger invalidate.

Comment: @dlam can you please give us working example how invalidate works. To be honest it's very difficult to understand for beginner how to learn and read from library. Thanks

Comment: `PagingSource` has a method called `invalidate`. Calling this method, calls the `pagingSourceFactory` lambda function in `Pager` class, thus creating a new instance of `PagingSource` that reflects new data from your source. Programmatically, The PagingSource abstract class has an instance of `InvalidateCallbackTracker` which handles this invalidation.

For more info: https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:paging/paging-common/src/main/kotlin/androidx/paging/PagingSource.kt?q=file:androidx%2Fpaging%2FPagingSource.kt%20class:androidx.paging.PagingSource

Answer (score 1):

To use the invalidate() method we need to wrap it in the `InvalidatingPagingSourceFactory`.

```
  private val pagingSourceInvalidatingFactory = InvalidatingPagingSourceFactory {
        PagingSource(
            repository = exampleRepository
        )
    }

val pager: Flow<PagingData<ExampleModel>> by lazy {
    Pager(
        config = PagingConfig(pageSize = PAGE_SIZE),
        pagingSourceFactory = pagingSourceInvalidatingFactory
    ).flow
}
```

And then you can freely use `invalidate()` on the `pagingSourceInvalidatingFactory`

Answer (score 0):

When We use adapter.refresh() method it will refresh the latest data and bind with the layout.

But It is not reLoading the recycler view with Position.
In that case, you will get the wrong position.

Because in DiffUtils you match correctly. So, whenever you refresh, it will bind only that new and not bonded data.

So, The solution is you have to make false the DiffUtils. In that case, PageSource will update the full list and the position will be updated.

Like : oldItem.id ==-1

```
 private val COMPARATOR = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<UnlimitData>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: UnlimitData, newItem: UnlimitData): Boolean =
            oldItem.id ==-1

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: UnlimitData, newItem: UnlimitData): Boolean = oldItem == newItem
    }
```